# Spacing between header on each line

Tags: html, css, header, styles

I am trying to add spacing between each line on my header. Some of the letters seem to overlap while others are very close to the next line. I tried adding `padding` but that is adding padding around the whole text rather than each line. Any help will be appreciated.

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L1jch0Lf/1/)**

Comment: you can use line-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `line-height` css verb:

```
line-height: 1.6em;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L1jch0Lf/3/

See the documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

Answer (score 1):

You can use unordered list for something like that. I highly suggest not using regular text, since I believe you're actually going to have some real elements behind it.

```css
#box {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul  {
  list-style: NONE;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
 <ul>
  <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></li>
  <li>Text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have more like a paragraph rather than a list

Comment: @user4756836 You can add anything you want in those lists. Check my edited example.

Answer (score 0):

```
line-height:150%;
```

The default line height in most browsers is about 110% to 120%

or

```
line-height: 30px;
```

or

```
line-height:1.5;
```